# How to remove old lines when low goes below it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am drawing support near pivot levels with a condition that there should be a doji (logic for it in the code) at the pivot point. This is plotting too many lines, even the lines which are not support anymore.
I want older lines to be removed when the low goes below the support line.

I am not able to figure out the code to remove the lines when the low breaks it.

Basically, I only want to show those lines which have not been broken.

In the image attached, I have marked the lines that should not be visible as the levels are broken

[image: Levels on the chart]

Below is my code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © kunthu

//@version=5
indicator("SR", "SR", true)

pivotBars                 = input.int(5)

var float pivotBarOpen    = 0.
var float pivotBarHigh    = 0.
var float pivotBarLow     = 0.
var float pivotBarClose   = 0.

pivotHighValue            = ta.pivothigh(pivotBars,pivotBars)
pivotLowValue             = ta.pivotlow(pivotBars,pivotBars)

pivotHighTrue             = na(pivotHighValue) ? false : true
pivotLowTrue              = na(pivotLowValue) ? false : true
doji                      = (high-low)/5 > math.abs(open-close)
barcolor(doji ? color.white : na, title = "Doji Bars", editable = false)

var line supportBottom    = na


dojiSupportCondition      = pivotLowTrue and doji[pivotBars] and not ta.crossunder(low, ta.valuewhen(pivotLowTrue, low[pivotBars], 1))

if dojiSupportCondition
    pivotBarOpen          := open[pivotBars]
    pivotBarHigh          := high[pivotBars]
    pivotBarLow           := low[pivotBars]
    pivotBarClose         := close[pivotBars]
    supportBottom         := line.new(bar_index - pivotBars, pivotLowValue, last_bar_index, pivotLowValue, xloc.bar_index, color = color.green)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the lines into an array and then looped through it to check if the lines have been undercut, deleting any that have.

```
//@version=5
indicator("SR", "SR", true)

pivotBars                 = input.int(5)

var float pivotBarOpen    = 0.
var float pivotBarHigh    = 0.
var float pivotBarLow     = 0.
var float pivotBarClose   = 0.

pivotHighValue            = ta.pivothigh(pivotBars,pivotBars)
pivotLowValue             = ta.pivotlow(pivotBars,pivotBars)

pivotHighTrue             = na(pivotHighValue) ? false : true
pivotLowTrue              = na(pivotLowValue) ? false : true
doji                      = (high-low)/5 > math.abs(open-close)
barcolor(doji ? color.white : na, title = "Doji Bars", editable = false)

var line supportBottom    = na
var lineArr = array.new<line>()


dojiSupportCondition      = pivotLowTrue and doji[pivotBars] and not ta.crossunder(low, ta.valuewhen(pivotLowTrue, low[pivotBars], 1))

if dojiSupportCondition
    pivotBarOpen          := open[pivotBars]
    pivotBarHigh          := high[pivotBars]
    pivotBarLow           := low[pivotBars]
    pivotBarClose         := close[pivotBars]
    lineArr.unshift(line.new(bar_index - pivotBars, pivotLowValue, last_bar_index, pivotLowValue, xloc.bar_index, color = color.green))

if lineArrMain.size() > 0 and lineArrBand.size() > 0
    for [idx,m] in lineArrMain
        if low < m.get_y1()
            m.delete()
            line.delete(lineArrBand.get(idx))
            lineArrMain.remove(idx)
            lineArrBand.remove(idx)

if lineArrMain.size() > 0 and lineArrBand.size() > 0
    for i = 0 to lineArrMain.size()-1
        linefill.new(lineArrMain.get(i), lineArrBand.get(i), #00ff0022)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir!
I have made some changes to the code and I am facing some issues.
I will answer my own question. If you could help me solve it, it would be of great help.
Thank You again sir

Comment: There is one small addition to the code sir.
We should add `max_lines_count = 500` to the indicator function if the no of lines exceeds 500, otherwise, the fill function does not work properly. In my observation.